# SUM rows by week syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, group-by, sum

I am using the following query

```
SELECT CONVERT(date,lot.Killdate) as KillDate
  ,lot.[LotNo]
  ,lot.[HotWeight]
  ,lot.[AverageYieldGrade]
  ,(lot.HeadShorn + lot.HeadUnshorn) as 'Total'
  ,(lot.HotWeight) / (lot.HeadShorn + lot.HeadUnshorn) as 'AvgWeight'  
  ,date.Date
  ,date.WeekOfYear
FROM [LambLot].[dbo].[LotHeader] lot, Master_Dim.dbo.DateDim date
WHERE CONVERT(date,lot.KillDate) = date.Date 
and lot.KillLocation = 1 
AND lot.HeadShorn > 0
AND lot.HeadUnshorn > 0
AND date.Year = 2016
group by lot.LotNo, lot.HeadShorn, lot.HeadUnshorn, lot.HotWeight lot.AverageYieldGrade, lot.KillDate, date.Date, date.WeekOfYear
order by date.WeekOfYear asc
```

Here is a copy of the output

```
    KillDate    LotNo   HotWeight   AverageYieldGrade   Total   AvgWeight           Date        WeekOfYear
1   2016-01-04  102     21603.5     2.28                348     62.0790229885057    2016-01-04  2
2   2016-01-04  103     2305.3      1.42                53      43.4962264150943    2016-01-04  2
3   2016-01-04  105     1159        0                   17      68.1764705882353    2016-01-04  2
4   2016-01-04  108     1493.6      0                   39      38.2974358974359    2016-01-04  2
5   2016-01-04  109     2982.8      0                   80      37.285              2016-01-04  2
```

What i would like to do is sum each row into the weekofyear. Essentially giving me 52 rows of output, with sums of each value in each column shown. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Something like... `select   datepart(yy,datecolumn) as YearNum, datepart(wk,datecolumn) as WeekNum, sum(someColumn) from someTable group by datepart(yy,datecolumn), datepart(wk,datecolumn)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to `SUM` by just `WeekOfYear`, you need to `GROUP BY` just week of year.  You have to decide how you handle the other values, here's one way that may make sense (with some expected output it'd be easier to figure out what you're really looking for):

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, MAX(lot.Killdate)) as KillDate
  ,MAX(lot.[LotNo]) -- ?? Does this really belong in this query?
  ,SUM(lot.[HotWeight])
  ,AVG(lot.[AverageYieldGrade])
  ,(SUM(lot.HeadShorn) + SUM(lot.HeadUnshorn)) as 'Total'
  ,SUM(lot.HotWeight) / (SUM(lot.HeadShorn) + SUM(lot.HeadUnshorn)) as 'AvgWeight'  
  ,MAX(date.Date)
  ,date.WeekOfYear
FROM [LambLot].[dbo].[LotHeader] lot, Master_Dim.dbo.DateDim date
WHERE CONVERT(date,lot.KillDate) = date.Date 
and lot.KillLocation = 1 
AND lot.HeadShorn > 0
AND lot.HeadUnshorn > 0
AND date.Year = 2016
group by date.WeekOfYear
order by date.WeekOfYear asc
```

Just remember: whatever columns you `GROUP BY` will be factored into how a distinct group is figured out.  Anything you don't have in your `GROUP BY` but want in your output just needs some kind of aggregate function (such as `MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG`, `SUM`, `COUNT`, etc.).

Comment: Excellent comment @Dan Field. I did not realize that in order to remove columns from the group by statement that I had to add an aggregate function. This is great. Thank you!!